# $rootScope stored inside the component $scope

Tags: angularjs

Hi I just got tasked with maintaining a client written in AngjularJs and im not very familiar with Angjular but I just found this piece of code that I believe to be pure insanity..

There is a service that fetches an array of types from an API then attaches it to the rootScope

```js
// just use a global, we'll need this array of types later
$rootScope.opts = opts;
```

The controller (which includes the service above)

```js
 //this cant be right
 $scope.$rootScope = $rootScope;

 $scope.setCategory = (type) => {
   // trust that the service has set the options into $rootScope
   const option = $scope.$rootScope.opts.find(
   typeOption => typeOption.name === type);
   return option;
 }
```

I would think it better to store the "opts" array in the service and just invoke it from the controller when needed ?

But before I nuke this code I must know if there any sense in doing it this way

Comment: Yeah for sure. You don’t assign $rootScope to the $scope. It would just be $rootScope.opts. And secondly the better option would be to use a service to get the opts and inject it into your controller. You are absolutely right. You don’t need $rootScope at all. Nuke that trash! Haha

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check, will definitely do that!

Comment: No problem. Sounds like you might have your work cut out for you. Good luck

Comment: yeah I wonder no more why im the 3rd dev to take over this project in 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the template associated with the controller uses `$rootScope` in its HTML. This is a very unstructured design and there are better ways to do it. Also a bit redundant because `$scope` already has a property named `$root` which points to the `$rootScope`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS API Reference - $rootScope properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$rootScope.Scope-properties)

Comment: And this component ng-includes no less than 10 other templates, am I right in assuming that this `$scope.$rootScope` might be referenced in their templates / controllers as well ?